# cloning from github when password has ! in it

Tags: linux, git, bash

I have a password that has ! in it and when  am trying to clone a repository from git using the following syntax:

```
  git clone https://username:password!@github.com/org/repository.git
```

I am getting this error:

```
 bash: !@github.com/org/repository.git: event not found
```

How can I fix it without changing password?

I am in Linux. I have used this in windows without any problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just backslash the exclamation mark. It has a special meaning in bash (history expansion).

```
git clone https://username:password\!@github.com/org/repository.git
```

You can also wrap it into *single* quotes (`'`):

```
git clone 'https://username:password!@github.com/org/repository.git'
```

Comment: I still got an error when trying to escape the ! with a backslash but wrapping in single-quotes worked